# Does RNA serve as the genetic material of some plants and animals along with viruses?

Tags: rna

My teacher mentioned that some plants and animals have RNA as genetic material but did not substantiate his statement  with examples. I'm wondering if it is so? 
I have searched the internet but have found no such information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no animals or plants with RNA genomes. There was a mistaken belief in the 1920s that plant genetic material was RNA whereas animals had DNA, but this was finally disproved by JN Davidson in the 1940s.